# Deleted user in Moodle still appear in the course completion table

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have 2 `courses` with different activities in them where all my `users` are `enrolled`.

After I completely `delete` some user, the data for course completions of the user is still in the table `mdl_course_completions`.

The users don't appear enrolled in the course, neither the grades are kept, only the completion data.

I don't want every time to delete users manually from the `mdl_course_completions` `table` in the `database`. 
Is there any workaround in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you removing users directly through an SQL query? I'd suggest always using the core methods (i.e. invoking a script that calls delete_user($user)) so that the plugins are able to remove any leftover data from their respective tables.

Depending on how you're deleting the users and your version of Moodle the following could be of use:

If you mean that the users are deleted through the front end then you may be able to hook into the core events API to run additional cleanup tasks

[Events API documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2)

Specifically there is an event for 'user_deleted' that you can use. You will need to set up an observer that sets up a callback to your custom script, i.e.

```
$observers = array(

    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\user_deleted',
        'includefile' => '/path/to/file',
        'callback'    => 'delete_cleanup',
    ),

);
```

[More information on event observers](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2#Event_observers)